# Find the integer solution of a equation.

Tags: number-theory

Find all integer solution of the equation $3a^2-b^2=1$.
The question seemed very easy. But I can't do it.
At first I tried it do using the theory of congruence. We know a perfect square is congruent to 1 modulo 4. But I can't find any way.I failed to factorise it, so please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Method**$\#1:$

$$b^2+1=3a^2\implies b^2\equiv-1\pmod3$$

But as $b\equiv-1,0,1\pmod3\implies b^2\equiv0,1\pmod3$

**Method**$\#2:$

If $3|b,b=3c;1=3(a^2-3c^2)$ which is impossible

So, $b\equiv\pm1\pmod3\implies b^2+1\equiv2\pmod3$

But $3a^2\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: #lab bhattacharjee : Please write  the full solution.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel, Please pinpoint your confusion.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel These methods are for you to digest, understand at your own pace and not intended as a full homework answer. Lab has given you enough information to provide a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Working $\bmod 4$, since you started along that road:

$$ a^2,b^2 \equiv \{0,1\} \bmod 4 \\
\implies 3a^2 \equiv \{0,3\} \bmod 4 \\
\implies 3a^2-b^2 \equiv \{0,3,-1,2\} \equiv \{0,2,3\}\bmod 4 \\
$$
Therefore $1$, or any value $k \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, is not a feasible outcome for $3a^2-b^2$.